# Trouble separating lists in order to use an element from it

Tags: python

I am trying to open a file and get the first word from that file 
and then compare if it is the same word
i.e. source_index.txt

```
TTTGATTAAT , source-document01012.txt , 0 , 9
TAATAGTTAG , source-document01012.txt , 6 , 15
TTAGTTTACT , source-document01012.txt , 12 , 21
```

and get  TTTGATTAAT in order to be used later.

extract from code

```
with open ('source_index.txt', 'r') as fsource:
    index1 = [line.strip().split(",") for line in fsource]

    with open ('susp_index.txt', 'r') as fsusp:
        index2 = [line.strip().split(",") for line in fsusp]

    if  index1[0] == index2[0]:
```

by using index1[0], it gives me the whole line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
with open ('source_index.txt', 'r') as fsource:
    index1 = [line.strip().split(",") for line in fsource]
```

returns a list of list.

So you should try `index[0][0]` instead of `index[0]`

Comment: When you split like that you are going to get a space at the end. You would get "TTTGATTAAT " instead of "TTTGATTAAT"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are looping through the entire file when you only want the first word in the first line

You only need to do this:

- Read the first line
- Split it by " ," (space and comma)
- Get the first item from that split

Here's the code:

```
with open ('source_index.txt', 'r') as fsource:
    index1 = fsource.readlines()[0].split(" ,")[0]
print(index1)

#TTTGATTAAT
```