# I want to sort a list by two elements but i am getting out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a list by `document` first and then `startPos`.
This is an extract of my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


        if tokens[0] == tokens2[0]:
            document = tokens[1]
            startPos = tokens[2]
            endPos = tokens[3]
            s = []
            if document not in s:
                s.append(document)
            if startPos not in s:
                s.append(startPos)
            if endPos not in s:
                s.append(endPos)
            li = s
            sorted(li, key = operator.itemgetter(0,1))
            print >> fmatches, li
```

I am getting

```
  File "./match.py", line 48, in <module>
    sorted(li, key = operator.itemgetter(0,1))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Ideally, I would like to have..

```
['source-document01211.txt', '4842', '4851']
['source-document01222.txt', '3162', '3171']
['source-document01222.txt', '20802', '20811']
['source-document01229.txt', '32586', '32595']
['source-document01245.txt', '8670', '8679']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sorted()` doesn't operate in-place, so that line doesn't accomplish anything useful.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: **sorted** returns a new object, sorting the one you give as an argument.  The parameters you're trying to use are for **sort**, a different method.  You might want **li.sort(...)** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding your code completely (I think it's not nearly doing anything useful at the moment) there are even a few issues. I am making some educated guesses based on the data your are dealing with, the desired output (which is not sorted by the way but probably should have been) and your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382071/trouble-separating-lists-in-order-to-use-an-element-from-it).

I am assuming that each list `s` represents a record of `[document, startPos, endPos]` and you probably want to gather a bunch of those records first and then store all these in `li`? I am further assuming your final goal is to then sort all the records in `li`.

The problems you have at the moment:

- `sorted(li)` returns a sorted list but doesn't change `li` itself. Since you didn't assign the result to anything your line is pretty much doing nothing as of now.
- lists are zero index based meaning `document = s[0]`, `startPos = s[1]`, ...
- You probably want to interpret `startPos` as a number when sorting (just guessing of course...) but it is given as a string.

The following does achieve all this:

```
li = [['source-document01211.txt', '4842', '4851'],
      ['source-document01222.txt', '3162', '3171'],
      ['source-document01222.txt', '20802', '20811'],
      ['source-document01229.txt', '32586', '32595'],
      ['source-document01245.txt', '8670', '8679']]

li.sort(key=lambda tup: (tup[0], int(tup[1])))
```

Your entire script is then probably meant to look somewhat like

```
li = []
for tokens in some_token_list:
    s = [token[i] for i in range(1, 4)]
    li.append(s)

li.sort(key=lambda elem: (int(elem[1]), int(elem[2])))
```

which could be even further reduced to a single line of code.

Since you set `s = []` before appending things to `s` you don't need to check if anything is in the list. It's empty by definition! You probably meant to write the above as `s = [token[i] for i in range(1, 4)]` (assuming you always want three items).

Again, I might be totally off but I think I am not.

Comment: Wow, you pretty much hit the nail on most of the stuff there. 

Okay, I have two texts, source-text.txt and susp-text.txt and I open them with this script in order to compare and see if there are any matching patterns and if there are, I want to print the source  document, start position and end position of the pattern. 

A problem though is that there isn't any pre existing list, so I don't know how I am going to use 'some_token_list'

Comment: To give you a hint, the start of the script is like this: *Edited OP*

Comment: You presumably extracted these from a file. My answer is not meant to give you a complete solution but to give you an idea of how to proceed further. Stackoverflow is no "please write my entire code for me" kind of website after all.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, thank you for your very helpful input!